# Cartoon about kids capturing monsters

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

I don't really remember a lot of the cartoon I remember that had 3D animation. In one episode I think the brother of one in the main group tried to be an alien/monster catcher but they don't want him to be in the group. Then this other group showed up and take the kid but the group turned out to be fake, they were aliens. Also they had Tron like suits and I think they used pistols.

Comment: If you remember anything else about this plot wise or when/where you saw it please [edit] your question to include those details!

Comment: What year did you see the cartoon? What country was you watching it in? Do you remember the name of the TV station that was showing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Monster Buster Club" was produced by French studio Marathon (Totally Spies) in conjunction with Canadian animation studio.

[image: Monster Buster Club posted showing the 4 kids in their Tron-like suits and their monster catching weapons]

Comment: Whilst the image matches the Tron suit description, does the plot match? Can you edit this to explain how it matches?

Answer (score 1):

Possible: *3Below: Tales of Arcadia*.

[image: 3Below: Tales of Arcadia poster showing two kids in their Tron-like suits, a big alien in his his and a cute little Corgi]

Comment: Same with my comment on your other answer here, could you edit this to explain how it matches?

Comment: You said Tron like suits

Comment: I'm not the question asker but have you posted this solely for the Tron-like suits part of the question? If so that isn't really much of a match on its own.